# using a for loop to cycle through a directory

Tags: r

I have to draw from 130 different .txt files to calculate the proportion of a given name each year. My program performs the calculation correctly, but when it goes to loop to the next file i get this error:

***Error in file(file, "rt")  : invalid 'description' argument***

```
baby = function(name, sex, data) {
  all.files = dir(path = data, pattern = ".txt")
  #print(all.files)
  proportion = vector()
  i = 1
  for(file in all.files ){
    direc = paste0(data, "/", file)

    data = read.csv(direc, sep = ",", header = FALSE)
    #print(data)

   name.row = which(data[,1] == name)
   print(name.row)

      if(data[name.row[1],2] == sex) {
     #print("hit")
        name.count = data[name.row[1],3]
       # print(name.count) 

   }
   if (data[name.row[2],2] == sex) {
      #print("miss")
     name.count = data[name.row[2],3]
    # print(name.count) 
    }
   print(name.count)


    total.count = sum(data[,3])
   # print(total.count)

    proportion[i] = name.count / total.count
    print(proportion)
    i = i + 1

    }
  return(proportion)

}
```

it should return a vector of proportions, one from each file, instead i only get through one file

Comment: You should print the value of `direc` before you `read.csv` to make sure it looks OK. It sounds like you are creating a bad file path. How exactly are you calling this function (ie what are you passing in)?

Comment: Please give feedback about answers so the community knows whether the problem is solved or not

Comment: thanks its all figured out

Answer (score 0):

You can use sapply to perform your job. Something like this might work:

```
sapply(list.files(path = "your_directory",
                  pattern = ".txt",
                  full.names = TRUE), 
       your_fun)
```

edit: Credits to this [source](https://www.instagram.com/p/B3WYfk7AoSG/).